Only last notification retrieved after phone turned back on - Expo notifications
I'm using expo notifications and expo-server-sdk-node to send notifications to my app.
If the phone is offline, on turning it back on, only the last notification is displayed.
What is strange is that if the notifications were sent less than 2 or 3 minutes ago, i can catch them all.
Same behavior on android and ios. And also same behavior with expo go or with an eas build profile preview.
Anyone has an idea of where the problem occurs ? Here is below how i send my notifications and how i catch them :
Sending

  let expo = new Expo({
    accessToken: process.env.EXPO_ACCESS_TOKEN,
    useFcmV1: true,
  });

  const allUsers = await User.find()

  let messages = []

  for (let user of allUsers) {
    if (!Expo.isExpoPushToken(user.push_token)) {
      console.log(`Push token ${user.push_token} is not a valid Expo push token`);
    }
    else {
      messages.push({
        to: user.push_token,
        sound: 'default',
        title,
        body: message,
        priority : 'high',
        channelId : 'boost-up',
        ttl: 604800,
        data : {
          collapse : false,
        }
      })
    }
  }


// Then i send all the chunks

Catching
  Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
        handleNotification: async () => ({
            shouldShowAlert: true,
            shouldPlaySound: true,
            shouldSetBadge: true,
        }),
    });



    const [notification, setNotification] = useState('');

    const notificationListener = useRef('');
    const responseListener = useRef('');


useEffect(() => {

        notificationListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener(notification => {
            setNotification(notification);
        });

        responseListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener(response => {
            console.log("RESPONSE :", response);
        });

        return () => {
            notificationListener.current &&
                Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(notificationListener.current);
            responseListener.current &&
                Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(responseListener.current);
        };
    }, [])

I've tried to put some fake data in the notifications (the "collapse : false") to make it non collapsible, in case the problem where there, but it didn't help.
